# Relating multiple table on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a beginner in MySQL and first time ask a question in here, so correct me if I'm wrong..

I have 4 tables like following :

```
Table A 
A_id   | A_description

Table B
B_id   | B_description

Table C
C_id   | C_description

Table D
D_id   | D_description
```

Now i want to make a new table which relate that 4 tables :

```
Table E
A_id  | B_id | C_id | D_id | D_description
```

The data representation should like this :

```
A    B    C    D   D_Description
================================
A1-> B1-> C1-> D1 ->Description
            -> D2 ->Description
       -> C2-> D1 ->Description
            -> D2 ->Description
  -> B2-> C1-> D1 ->Description
            -> D2 ->Description
       -> C2-> D1 ->Description
            -> D2 ->Description

and so on for A2 ...
```

I started to make the database like these :

```
Table A 
A_id   | A_description

Table B
B_id   | A_id | B_description
```

which the `B_id` and `A_id` is a unique constraint. 
But i  don't know  how to make the structure of the remaining tables these way.

So, how is the database structure should be? (Or how the first 4 tables structure should be?) Thanks :)

EDIT : 
The result table should be like this :

```
Table A
A_id | A_Description
  1    explanation
  2    another explanation

Table B
A_id | B_id | B_Description
  1     1    description
  2     1    my description
  2     2    your description
```

Where B_id column can contain the same data if the A_id is different (like unique constraint)

Comment: `Table C -> C_id, B_id, C_Description` and `Table D -> D_id, C_id, D_Description` You are in the right track. Without any explanation about the data, this can be a solution or you can use you own suggestion (4 tables each with its ID and description and one to link then all) with a unique constraint on those four ids (a,b,c,d) to avoid duplicates.

Comment: thanks for your help! :) @JorgeCampos

Comment: I guess you need three many-to-many relation tables: Table A_B(A_id, B_id), Table B_C(B_id, C_id), Table C_D(C_id, D_id).

Comment: If so, can I use the JOIN query later to link D_id to A_id later?
And if I use only 2 columns in B, C, or D table (ex : B_id and B_description), it would go error because the requirement prerequisites B_id can contain same data. So I include the foreign key from the previous tables and make unique constraint with current table's ID to identify each row (which I did on the table B on question). Am I on the right track? @PaulSpiegel

Comment: Sorry - your question isn't clear enough. Try to add a real world example. However - if my guess is correct your query would be: `SELECT A_id, B_id, C_id, D_id, D_description FROM D JOIN C_D USING (D_id) JOIN B_C USING (C_id) JOIN A_B USING (B_id)`.

Comment: Please check my edited question for example :) That's what I mean with "B_id can contain same data." Thank you for the query. I'd try that if I finished the database structure. @PaulSpiegel

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want cross join:

```
Select a.id, b.id, c.id, d.id, d.description
From a cross join b cross join c cross join d;
```

Note: this will fill in all the column values, but that is how SQL result sets normally work.  Formatting the rows is usually done at the application layer.

You can save the results in a table, which acts to relate them.

Comment: His question is about how to alter the tables to add foreign keys that relate them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That's close, but each rows should not combined 'automatically' to each rows of other table, which what cross join does (correct me if I wrong). The data is not same for each combination - @GordonLinoff

Comment: Yes, that was I mean. I confuse about the correct way to relate those tables @Barmar